# Angular2 CLI deploy, useHash

Tags: angular, hash, deployment, build

I'm currently trying to deploy my Angular2 app using CLI build, now this is working perfectly, i'm copying the content of the dist to an folder on the root of my server.

Now it's running great but when i reload the page on a route it's not working. After some googling i found out `useHash` in `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })` solves this problem.

So my question is: Is there's another way, because i prefer pretty URL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your server, you have to add a rewrite rule to redirect everything to your `index.html` page. It will solve the problem.

In `Apache2`, add in your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

In `IIS`

```
<rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="[a-zA-Z]*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```

Also keep in mind that you will probably have to add an exception for your `API` route (by convention, /api).

Comment: Let me try some .htaccess rules and will get back at it later

Comment: Works perfectly thanks mate! (will accept answer in 7 mins).

Comment: No problem, don't forget to search next time!